# Integration: Gauss quadrature formula of the Integral $\int_{-1}^1f(x)\sqrt{|x|}dx$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, quadrature

I want to find the formula for the Gauss quadrature that integrate the Integral $\int_{-1}^1f(x)\sqrt{|x|}\, dx$ exactly for every cubic polynomial $f$.

What exactly do we have to do here?

Is $\sqrt{|x|}$ the weighting function?

Could you explain me all the procedures step by step?

Comment: It often helps to share what you have tried.

Comment: if $\sqrt{|x|}\$ is the weighting function, then I only know that we need to find a family of orthogonal poinomials in the interval [-1,1]. However, I don't know where to start and how to proceed. The exercise also says to determine a Gaussian quadrature formula with a minimum number of nodes.

Comment: Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the integration rule is to be exact for polynomials of degree three, you will get four conditions that can set four parameters. So, we want a rule of the form $Q(f) = w_0 f(x_0) + w_1 f(x_1)$, such that
$$
Q(1) = I(1), Q(x) = I(x), Q(x^2)=I(x^2), Q(x^3)=I(x^3).
$$

This leads to the system
$$
\begin{cases}
w_0+w_1 = \frac 43\\
w_0 x_0 + w_1 x_1 = 0\\
w_0 x_0^2 + w_1 x_1^2=\frac 47\\
w_0x_0^3+w_1 x_1^3 = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Now you just need to solve for $x_0, x_1, w_0, w_1$, which is not hard in this case, to get
$$
Q/f)= \frac 23 f\left(-\sqrt{\frac 37}\right)+\frac 23 f\left(\sqrt{\frac 37}\right).
$$

Comment: But I have here $I(x)=\int_{-1}^1f(x)\sqrt{|x|}dx$ and not $I(x)=\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx$

Comment: Sure, when I write $I(x)$, it stands for $\int_{-1}^1 x \sqrt{|x|} dx$.

Comment: And how do you know for example that the result of $I(x^2)$ is $4/7$? The polynomial $ f(x)$ can be any polynomial, right? so how do you know that the result is $4/7$?

Comment: @MarcoDJ01 $I(x^2) = \int_{-1}^1 x^2 \sqrt{|x|} dx = 2 \int_0^1 x^{5/2} dx = \cdots = \frac 47$.

Comment: @MarcoDJ01 The integration rule is linear... If it is exact for $1, x, x^2, x^3$, it is exact for all polynomials with degree $\leq 3$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!